# How to get data from @model and display on angular?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

```
@model BetXOnline.CustomPaging.MatchResult
```

i have this in my cshtml page, and now i want to display the results like this

```
<li ng-repeat="item in @Model.Matches">
    {{item.Description}}
</li>
```

And nothing happens, no errors, no crashes just empty page, it is in a partial view.

Comment: Angular runs on the browser, on the HTML that was generated as a result of a view's rendering. The model isn't available there. As for crashes, there definitely was a Javascript crash that would be obvious if you had the Developer Tools of your browser opened. I also suspect you haven't enabled Javascript debugging on the server

Comment: yeah, i get this error : ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: That's a networking error. That's not related to Angular or MVC. Check your credentials and  start a network capture from the Developer Tools to see which call fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use there the `Model` that you pass in your view, through your controller.  Assuming that you want to use Angular JS, you have to have in your scope an object that contains the matches. Then you can use it this way.

Otherwise, you could make the same, without using Angular JS, like below:

```
@foreach(var match in @Model.Matches)
{
    <li>match.Description</li>
}
```

Comment: Oh well, the object is not a JSON object in the Model i need to fix that first I will try it and keep updates